# argument problem to publish msg to a certain topic

Tags: ros, gazebo, rostopic--pub, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello. i roslaunch a turtlebot in an empty world, and i am trying to send data in a topic but i am having a problem. the topic is **/gazebo/set_model_state**, which have a type of **gazebo_msgs/ModelState**.
so the arguments i have to include into rostopic -pub command are:

```
string model_name
geometry_msgs/Pose pose
  geometry_msgs/Point position
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
  geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
    float64 w
geometry_msgs/Twist twist
  geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
  geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
string reference_frame
```

i've read the tutorials, but they didn't help me with it. please, if anyone nose how to publish msg to that, help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32817/argument-problem-to-publish-msg-to-a-certain-topic/) by [grge](https://answers.ros.org/users/2213/grge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know there is a way to publish such messages via command line, but for more complex messages i recommend to write a simple publisher like in the tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

You can use the same code to write a simple publisher with the only difference that instead of a string you will need to post a pose. Code should look similar to the following:

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('geometry_msgs')    
(...)
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
(...) 
my_pose = Pose()
my_pose.position.x = 0.1
my_pose.position.y = 0.2
(...)
        pub.publish(my_pose)
(...)
```

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0